# How to run run output of Popen command through a regular expression

Tags: python, regex, subprocess, popen

I'm trying to execute a command using Popen and search through the output using a regex to find a UserID.  When I run the code below and have `if reg_ex.search(line)` code block commented out, the command runs successfully (although I don't have my userID).  As soon as I uncomment out the regex code, the command itself fails.

Any ideas why this regex if statement makes the command itself fail when I'm just iterating through output and any idea how to get the userId I need from the output?  I've already confirmed the regex itself works when run separately (although for those that want it, the output line for regex will look like this `u'userId': u'userID_in–question'}`.

```
import re
import subprocess

#command I want to run
command = "add-user " + FirstName + " " + LastName + " " + Email + " " + Phone

#Regex to find userId in output
reg_ex_find = re.compile('userId')
reg_ex_replace = re.compile("(""u'userId""|\s|:|}|')")

#call command
process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

for line in iter(process.stdout.readline, b''):
     print line
     if reg_ex_find.search(line):
            UserId = line
            reg_ex_replace.sub('',UserId) 
process.stdout.close()
process.wait()
print process.returncode
```

Comment: What exactly does «the command itself fails » mean?

Comment: I don't see `reg_ex` defined anywhere.

Comment: Also, instead of awkwardly deleting part of the string like that, why don't you add a capture group to your regex, of which you will only need one now.

Comment: Updated reg_ex to reg_ex_find (woops) and used capture group recommended by Mad Physicist and it now works.  Obviously the first update was required but switching to capture group solved the issue. Thanks!